# What would we have to find to prove supersymmetry correct?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model

What would we have to find to prove that supersymmetry is true?

Comment: If we find at least one of the particles that it suggests

Answer (score 1):

You can never prove a theory you can only falsify it!
Since there are for example predictions by MSSM (minimal supersymmertric standard model),
that there are new particles in the energy-range observable by the LHC, a new particle with the predicted mass would suggest that MSSM (which is one of many supersymmetric theories) is "true".

But until now no such particle was observed.

Comment: Supersymmetry is not a theory, it is a part of many theories. And strangely enough, this part can easily be proven true. Just like the fact that there are e.g. neutrinos.